# Twilio Transfer Current Call to other Worker

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to transfer current call to other worker but my calls wont push through. Maybe Im missing something.

```
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $response->say(
        'Your call is now being redirected',
        ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
    );
    $dial = $response->dial();
    $dial->client('client:agentjoe');
    print $response;
```

Comment: Hi drex! how did you figured it out?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too!  Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/979/